# Provided certificate is not a valid self signed. Please provide either a valid self-signed certificate or certificate chain

Tags: amazon-web-services

I receive this error when I try to import a certificate on AWS ACM.

> Provided certificate is not a valid self signed. Please provide either a valid self-signed certificate or certificate chain.

The certificated I have are initially in **.pfx** format and I use **sslshopper**: https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html to convert them into pem. There is only **certificate body** and **private key** present in the converted pem format and no **certficate chain**. Can this be the reason of this error. 
But I thought cert chain is optional .

The format of private key and cert body seems to be correct and is enclosed between

```
---Begin cert body/privateKey
---End cert body/privateKey
```

[image: error]

What can be the issue here ?

The cert body and the cert private key seems to be ok to me as it clearly shows me the name,expiry date etc once I paste the contents into the respective fields (please refer the green content in the attached screenshot.)

Comment: How did you sign the cert? What process did you follow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Somehow the issue was because of the missing cert chain. Received cert chain from the cert provider and  used all 3 (key,cert body & cert chain) while uploading it on ACM and all worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

Certificate body enter (server.crt)

Certificate private key enter (server.key)

Certificate Certificate chain enter (server.ca-bundle)

Comment: I do have `*crt` and `*key` files. How can I generate `*.ca-bundle` file?

Comment: I got mine from comodo. everything was in the zip file which they provided. You should follow up with whoever provided you the crt and key files.

Answer (score 3):

**Cert Body should be in this format**

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
#Your GlobalSign SSL Certificate#
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
#GlobalSign Intermediate Certificate#
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

**Cert chain should be in this format:**

Your completed file should be in this format:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
#Your GlobalSign SSL Certificate#
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
#GlobalSign Intermediate Certificate#
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
#GlobalSign Root Certificate#
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Note that all of the above needs to be converted to PEM format for AWS to accept it.

eg:  `openssl x509 -inform PEM -in yourCertContainingTheAbove3Cert.cer`

Comment: In my case, I missed to add the second begin-end block of Cert Chain.

Answer (score 2):

I did not have Certificate chain initially, just certificate itself and private key. As mine was wildcard (*.example.com), I went with Firefox to an url (another.example.com) that was working on none-AWS platform, clicked the lock, Connection Secure -> More information -> View certificate and here you go - the link to get the missing Chain:

[image: missing Chain]

Answer (score 0):

You have to find a file with a name My_CA_Bundle.txt or similar to it.
You will get it from the certificate provider as soon as you certificate gets approved.